# How to open two browsers at the same time by using selenium java

Tags: xml, automated-tests, testng

Any idea to open two browsers at the same for selenium tests. I have tried Parallel execution but this method not opening at the same two browsers.

my test code:

public class akramTest extends BaseClass {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(akramTest.class);

```
@Test(description = " login Test")

public void testScaledScurm_2() throws IOException, Exception {


    log.info("URL is opened");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "URL is opened)");
    driver.get(planningPokerURL);

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}


@Test(description = " login Test")

public void testScaledScurm_1() throws IOException, Exception {


    log.info("URL is opened");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "URL is opened)");
    driver.get(planningPokerURL);

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
```

}

Still getting one browser at the same time and in the same browser afterwhile opened a new test URL. Expecting two separate browsers should open.

Comment: Here is my testng.xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

  <test name="TestonFirefox">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.agilibo.testScripts.Develop.akramTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: Where comes the driver from?